# create multi-normal data in R using mvrnorm

Tags: r

I was using `mvrnorm` to generate data from multi-normal distribution with the mean `mu <- rep(0,4)` and `Sigma` be some positive definite symmetric matrix. However, I found that the last element in the vector I am generating is always `0`, any ideas about why is that?

```
> mvrnorm(n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
[1]  0.1813268 -0.8993918  0.7461007  0.0000000
> mvrnorm(n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
[1] 3.2539025 2.9855514 0.7313427 0.0000000
> mvrnorm(n = 1, mu, Sigma, tol = 1e-6, empirical = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE)
[1] -0.8133201 -1.0011971 -0.3800518  0.0000000
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks for the responses, yes, I checked the `Sigma`, there is something wrong with it.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your `Sigma`. This example works fine for me with `Sigma = diag(4)`.

Comment: Same here as Ozan147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your `Sigma` is not deemed full rank under `tol = 1e-6`. However, the way that `mvrnorm` does rank-detection is a bit odd. See inside `MASS::mvrnorm`:

```
eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
ev <- eS$values
if (!all(ev >= -tol * abs(ev[1L]))) 
    stop("'Sigma' is not positive definite")
X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n)
#[...omitted...]
X <- drop(mu) + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), p) %*% t(X)
```

Instead of

```
ev >= tol * abs(ev[1L])
```

it does

```
ev >= -tol * abs(ev[1L])
```

Therefore, you must have negative eigenvalues to get rank-deficiency.